# Upgrade the python version in Existing Anaconda Environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

In the conda enviroment, my python version is upgraded to `python-3.7`, but I want to use the previous `python-3.6`. Is it possible to downgrade the python version in the environment?

Answer (score 1):

Why not create new environment specifying version 3.6 like so:

```sh
conda create -n myenv python=3.6
```

orrrr if you want to downgrade an existing environment version

1. Find the version you want:

```sh
conda search python
```

2. Install it

```sh
conda install python=3.6.2
```